# Which part of the body has the most nerve receptors?

Tags: neurology, nerves, tactile-touch

I am studying a non-medical field so please bear with me.

Which part of the flat skin has the most nerve receptors?

I plan to build a grid of vibrators.

Comment: Good question but I edited according to your own suggestion because asking which part of the body is most sensitive is mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately, your last edit completely changed the nature of the question and invalidated the two answers you had. Going forward, what do you mean by "flat skin?" Are the lips flat skin? How about finger tips?

Comment: What @CareyGregory said, and doubly so. And what shall those vibes effect? In a grid? Arouse or relax? Genuine massage or erotic? Some other 'fun'?

Comment: Again, I do apologise for this. @CareyGregory any flat surface in the skin where a square could be attached.

Comment: @LangLangC , I am after perception of shapes with a vibrator grid. e.g. vibrating a star shaped formation in the grid.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you had said what you were trying to do, you would have had good answers by now.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about [Tactile corpuscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactile_corpuscle) or Meissner's corpuscles and [Lamellar corpuscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamellar_corpuscle) it would be the  fingertips followed by lips.

I did not find a reference in English, only a [German](https://books.google.de/books?id=jwUjBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA376&lpg=PA376&dq=%22Meissner-K%C3%B6rperchen%22+h%C3%B6chste+dichte&source=bl&ots=oEPxFkoYdY&sig=bXTN27hyrrCBvvqfvYgTt5IMEDg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO2tS23YbXAhWkIsAKHbETCy04ChDoAQgvMAI#v=onepage&q=%22Meissner-K%C3%B6rperchen%22%20h%C3%B6chste%20dichte&f=false):

> Die Fingerspitzen weisen die höchste Rezeptorendichte auf. Damit wird Begreifen möglich.
>
> <sup>*Lang, Phillip, Lang, Florian*: Basiswissen Physiology, Springer-Verlag, 2007; Seite 376</sup>
>
> The fingertips have the highest density of receptors. This is why grasping is possible.
>
> <sup>Translation into English</sup>

The all over highest density in receptors can be found in the [Fovea centralis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fovea_centralis).

Comment: I can verify the German source.

Comment: +1 for crossing language barriers.  I can't find any English sources to verify anything regarding this...

Comment: @bummi I intended to mean Tactile corpuscle. I am searching for a flat skin surface which is really sensitive to vibration. I plan to build a grid of vibrators.

Answer (score 2):

The largest organ in your body does -- the skin.

The most sensitive area would be any distal (meaning the farthest away) extremities.  Areas that require fine control (such as dexterity).  Your finger tips or genitals would be #1.

Comment: Sensitive and most receptors are not necessarily identical. You might need a bit more refernces ;) How about: [a penfield homunculus](http://nobaproject.com/images/shared/images/000/000/208/original.png)

Comment: HAHAH I haven't see that picture in forever!  You'd think the most concentrated area of cutaneous receptors would be most sensitive (that was my rationale). Where would you say it is? Gotta be careful what you google lol

Comment: Absolute number or relative density? What is meant by "body part"? Which *type* of receptor? As phrased in the Q as I read it: the brain. Sensory receptors are several subtypes of "receptor". [Sensory Neuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_neuron)

Comment: I was thinking 1st order neurons (not interneurons)...

Comment: As the Q is imho imprecise in wording, this opens the possible answers to cover multiple bases…

Comment: Very true!  I'm curious now -- how would you answer if we assume the question says absolute number of sensory receptors and  highest concentration of sensory receptors (I can't find anything on either of these)....

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the question. I was looking for a flat skin which contained the most receptors. I plan to build a grid of vibrators.

Comment: +1 for divining the actual nature of the question the OP didn't reveal until today.

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to build a vibrator, you need to look for erogenous zones, not just sensitive zones

> An erogenous zone (from Greek ἔρως, érōs "love" and English -genous "producing" from Greek -γενής, -genḗs "born") is an area of the human body that has heightened sensitivity, the stimulation of which may generate a sexual response, such as relaxation, the production of sexual fantasies, sexual arousal and orgasm.
>
> <sup>*[Wikipedia.Org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erogenous_zone#Specific_zones)*</sup>

[This article gives a good overview](http://www.cirp.org/library/anatomy/winkelmann/):

> **There are two types of erogenous zones: nonspecific and specific. Those of the nonspecific type depend upon exaggeration of a basic tickle sensation.** Specific erogenous zones, the mucocutaneous zones of human and animal, have special neural and cutaneous anatomic characteristics. The mucocutaneous end-organs in any given species appear to be identical in all of the the zones. The endings of the primates are markedly different from those of lower animals. **Development of the nerve endings is principally postfetal and may coincide with the organization of oral, anal and genital patterns of behavior.**
>
> <sup>*Winkelmann, RK. (1959). "[Erogenous zones: their nerve supply and significance](http://www.cirp.org/library/anatomy/winkelmann/)". Mayo Clin Proc. 34 (2): 39–47.*</sup>

Comment: Ouh, psychoanalytical concepts. You're dirty, dirty. Pfui ;) / But srsly: I fear the question isn't finished yet.

Comment: @LangLangC Well, my top tags are masturbation and sexuality. I do have a reputation to keep. I don’t think OP has what he wants either,  it he got what he asked for. I‘ll rollback any other edits. In fact, it would be reasonable enough to rollback this edit as well. Please ping me though so I can delete my answer...

Comment: Why delete it, now? The OP is in danger of wanderin into offtopicstan. And the first two answers don't fit any longer. But as Q is phrased now this answer hilights effectively "Don't do that, try this instead"

Comment: Agreed. But I'd suggest waiting a bit with that. OP should know best what he intends. Maybe he finds a way to get it 'all under one hat'.

Comment: @LangLangC I meant my answer would be off-topic and your answers on-topic. Stupid big thumbs. Let’s see what OP decides...

Comment: @Narusan-sedated Actually, the 2 answers are not really off the topic. They have given me ideas. I am not after the Tickling sensation. I am after the identification of shapes in a grid of vibrator. e.g. vibrating a star shaped formation in a 8x8 grid.